# Why does cron.hourly not care about the existence of anacron?

Tags: cron

This question came up over in [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4917515#4917515).

Why does the default `/etc/crontab` not check for existence (and executable flag) of `/usr/sbin/anacron` for the hourly entry?

My `/etc/crontab`:

```
# m h dom mon dow user  command
17 *    * * *   root    cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
47 6    * * 7   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly )
52 6    1 * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly )
```

What makes hourly different from the others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

anacron is running on a daily basis. It is not built to let jobs run on a hourly basis, so it is useless to test for anacron when an hourly job is started. To quote [anacron(8)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/anacron.8):

> Anacron  can  be  used to execute commands periodically, with a
>   frequency specified in days.  Unlike cron(8), it does not assume that
>   the machine is running continuously.  Hence, it can be used on
>   machines that aren't running 24 hours a day, to control daily, weekly,
>   and  monthly  jobs  that  are usually controlled by cron.

The other regularly executed jobs should only be executed by cron, when anacron is **not** installed.